# None in boost.python

Tags: c++, python, boost

I am trying to translate the following code

```
d = {}
d[0] = None
```

into C++ with boost.python

```
boost::python::dict d;
d[0] = ?None
```

How can I get a None object in boost.python?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is no constructor of `boost::python::object` that takes a `PyObject*` (from my understanding, a ctor like that would invalidate the whole idea if mapping Python types to C++ types anyway, because the PyObject* could be anything). According to the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/python/doc/v2/object.html#object-spec-ctors):

> `object();`
>
> Effects: Constructs an object managing a reference to the Python `None` object.

Answer (score 3):

You could use:

```
d[0] = d.get(0)
```

`d.get` defaults to `None` if you don't specify a default value.